Question regarding impulse response functions (IRFs)
My understanding is, IRF of output ($Y$) to monetary shock ($\epsilon$) is a set of partial derivatives, i.e., IRF of output ($Y$) to monetary shock ($\epsilon$) is {$\partial Y_{t+j}/ \partial \epsilon_t, j = 0,1,2,3,4...$}.
If expansionary monetary shock occurs at time $t$, then, change in monetary shock at time $t$ is negative $\partial \epsilon_t<0$. Then, if IRF of output at time $t$ is negative, shouldn't we conclude "output increases at time $t$ with decrease in the interest rate" instead of "output decreases at time $t$ with decrease in the interest rate." I am asking this question because all the papers I read say, "output decreases at time $t$ with decrease in the interest rate."

Your reading of the literature is mistaken. The standard literature (e.g. a host of papers by Larry Christiano) on the effect of monetary policy shows that output falls if interest rates increase.

Thank you so much @jpfeifer I wrote this oppositely. Silly me. Would it possible to help me out with a question.  Should the IRF of consumption to negative productivity shock be negative or positive? I would think negative but I am little bit confused because IRF is a set of partial derivatives correct? Then, if ∂et <0 and since shock decreases consumption, ∂Ct<0 , so, ∂Ct/∂et have to be > 0. What am doing I wrong? $C_t$ is consumption and $e_t$ is productivity shock.

The fraction $\partial c/\partial \varepsilon$ only give the sign. You still need to multiply it with the actual shock you are considering. The total effect is $\partial c/\partial \varepsilon\times \Delta \varepsilon$. The partial derivative is usually positive (C increases after a positive shock), but given that you multiply the expression by a negative shock you are considering, the overall effect/IRF is negative after a negative shock.
